# how to use grep for specific files?

Tags: bash, grep, ls

for example I type

```
ls -altr | grep "23 Dec"
```

so it will show files for 23 Dec only and I want to use grep for them, like

```
ls -altr | grep "23 Dec" | xargs grep -l "some_string"
```

but this doesn't work)

How to do that?

Comment: OS or what distribution is it?

Comment: @warl0ck Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga) 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5

Comment: Note that you really [shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use your way, try maybe:

```
ls -altr | grep "23 Dec" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -i grep -l "some_string" {}
```

or with `find` I would do:

```
find . -type f -newermt 2012-12-23 ! -newermt 2012-12-24 -exec grep -l "some_string" {} \;
```

In the find command, don't forget the escaped semicolon. Also note that find works much the same way as `xargs` when used with the -exec option.

Comment: doesn't work :( `grep: invalid option -- -
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.`

Comment: yes, you need awk to print the right column that contains the filename, if you want to use xargs.

Comment: when I use find it says: invalid predicate -newermt

Comment: did you copy and paste the command above? it works fine for me. also, what OS are you running and what version of find are you using (`find -version`). in my case, i'm using `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga) 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 
GNU find version 4.2.27

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The `find` solution is good.

Comment: @VextoR Your `find` is too old to have the `-newermt` option. You'll have to do this the old-fashioned way: create reference files with `touch -d 2012-12-23 start; touch -d 2012-12-24 end` and run `find -newer start ! -newer end …`.

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to find some files, that was modified on a specific date,

there would be no need for pipe, (ls uses modify time by default)

`find . -type f -newermt 2012-12-23 ! -newermt 2012-12-24 -iname '*some_string*'`

Comment: it says:

`find . -type f -newermt 2012-12-24 ! -newermt 2012-12-25 -iname '*50424876*'
find: invalid predicate `-newermt'`